# Formatting DateTime Issue SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

1. My date time datatype is datetime returns as **2011-08-23
   00:00:00.000** As I want to group by Month. So, I'm
   using`Month(Fields!DueDate.Value)` as expression inside my SSRS. 
   But, I am always getting grouping error: `conversion from string
   "02/13/2012" to type Date is not valid`
2. I'm also having #Error in displaying datetime field. For that case,
   I use the expression : `=format(Fields!DueDate.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy"`
   If I don't format it is showing no #Error. But it is not in correct
   format I want.
3. As because of Formatting Date Problem, I am unable use Visibility
   setting too. =Month(DueDate.value) = Parameter.Date.Value 
   Anyone can help me out with those above issue? I will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
   (P.S I can only change at presentation level)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the returned column is datetime?

Comment: When i check in the Design Mode of the Database table inside SSMS, it shows datetime as datatype.

Comment: 1. Try `Month(CDate(Fields!DueDate.Value))`
2. You're probably getting this `#Error` due to #1.

Comment: @WEI_DBA, When I apply it, it is displaying **#Error** in some lines and **dd MMM yyyy** in some lines. The text box property is in Date Format(31 Jan 2000-format).

Comment: Does the error related to SQL language ,by the way?

Comment: There is something seriously incorrect. I tried to format Fields!DueDate.Value in Text property to dd-MMM-yyyy alone, it is not formatting this way. Its format is always MM-dd-yy .

Comment: Remove the text box property formatting and leave in the `Month(CDate(Fields!DueDate.Value))`. See if that changes the error.